# Angular - Different sessionStorage behavior between IE 11 and Chrome

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, session-storage

I am using sessionStorage to transfer some settings from one browser tab to another tab. My sessionStorage is populated with data during a bootstrap process. So, at the run phase I am doing something like this:

```
if ($window.localStorage.getItem('loadNewTab')) {
    // Move parameters to session storage
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem('Params', $window.localStorage.getItem('Params'));
}
```

After closing the second tab and refreshing the first one in Chrome I have sessionStorage blank, but in IE it has values that were created during second's tab bootstrap. Even if I am doing/understanding something wrongly why Browsers behave differently?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage/sessionStorage outside of $window?

Comment: I think I did. Same.

Comment: I believe that reloading the tab in Chrome causes a complete reload, which would mean that the sessionStorage values would be wiped out. Each browser is a different piece of software from a different company. Expecting each one to perform exactly like the others is not realistic.

Comment: If you are wanting information to pass between tabs, you need a service in your app that checks localStorage/sessionStorage periodically (30 seconds?) and updates the required data.